# Timed out exception while registering with push notifications in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to register with BlackBerry push notifications, but it shows a time out exception.

Here is the code i wrote

```
 HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url+;interface=wifi,Connector.READ, false); 

/**
 * Attempts to register this device with the BlackBerry Push server. This 
 * method also alerts the user whether the registration was successful 
 * or not.
 * 
 * @return True if the registration was successful, false otherwise.
 */

public boolean registerForService()
{
    if( !isRadioConnected() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        // Open a connection with the BB Push server and request registration
        byte[] encryptedData = connectAndRead(REGISTER_URL);

        // Open a new connection and register using the encrypted url.
        final String encryptedParam = new String(encryptedData);
        String encryptedUrl = BBP_SERVER + "/mss/PD_subReg?osversion="
        + getDeviceSoftwareVersion()+ "&model="
        + DeviceInfo.getDeviceName() + "&" + encryptedParam 
        + ";ConnectionType=mds-public;deviceside=false";

        byte[] statusCodeData = connectAndRead(encryptedUrl);
        resultCode=  new String(statusCodeData);
        // Status code sent back to the application from the BB Push server
       String statusCode = new String(statusCodeData);

        // Note: Developers should also register with the Content Provider 
        // in order to notify the server that it can push data to this 
        // device.

        // If registration succeeded then start listening to messages 
        // from the server.
        if( (statusCode.equals(StatusCode.REGISTER_SUCCESSFUL) || statusCode
                .equals(StatusCode.USER_ALREADY_SUSCRIBED)))           
        {
            _dataListener = new ListeningThread();
            _dataListener.start();

            showDialogAndWait("Registration Succeeded."+resultCode+responseCode);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            showDialogAndWait("Registration Failed\nStatus Code: " + statusCode+resultCode+responseCode);
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch(final Exception e )
    {
        showDialogAndWait("Registration Error\n" + e.toString()+resultCode+responseCode);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is your device otherwise connected to the network?   Can you browse to a web page, for example?    The push service requires network connectivity.

Answer (score -2):

Simple things to do in Blackberry push notification, I got success by doing the following things

1. Use Blackberry device, which have BIS plan
2. Your content provider should be accessible publicly